# How can I restore my single-player game progress in GTA5 after an online game wiped out my saves?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I don't know what just happened, but I know this.

I just tried to join an Online game.  To my surprise I got in, but what I'm angry about is that before (first time joining Online), I had a 82% completion in Single-player, but for some reason, all my saves got reverted to beginning Franklin.

What do I do? Is there any fix? Did the online feature just wipe out my saves?

Comment: Have you tried loading an earlier save, like a manual quicksave?

Comment: Might sound stupid but maybe contact Rockstar? They could have a answer.

Comment: @Nolonar Tried doing that, it seems all my saves got reverted to the beginning.  I tried looking through game files, but all my save files are now 0% completion. This is really, really frustrating.

Comment: My friend just went through the same thing. With Multi-player coming out today (or came out) some accounts have been wiped. He found a site though where it said that they would fix this in a hidden update next week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in GTA online that caused Story Mode save files to become corrupted when switching from Online to Story.  [There has been a title update to fix this.](http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/news/article/51522/gta-online-new-title-update-available-today-and-more)

It won't restore your character, but Rockstar is giving everyone who played online during the age of strife(October) [$500,000 in in-game cash for their online characters](http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/news/article/51565/grand-theft-auto-online-half-a-million-gta-stimulus-package-this)